# Materials that don't absorb

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, issur-vheter

If a utensil can't become meat or milk through bliya, (like wood does) then is it ever possible to become non-kosher?

Comment: Now glass, according to Sefardim, never absorbs. Clean it thoroughly and you're done.

Comment: @Shalom That sounds like an answer: if a material doesn't absorb then it can't become non-kosher. Anything beyond that is just science not Halakha. If you could source this principle that would be great.

Comment: Wood can't become meat or milk through bliya? Are you sure? Source?

Comment: Scientifically it's not possible for wood to absorb flavoring because of the material. It could be thought as electrons passing through a metal object, however they can't pass through a wooden one.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed a utensil that doesn't absorb cannot become non-kosher.

Glass, according to Sefaradim, doesn't absorb and, if clean, can be used for meat and dairy. As such it cannot become non-kosher ([SA OC 451:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.451.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), see also for instance [here](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=4337)).

> Maran Rabbeinu Ovadia Yosef zt”l ruled in his works and Torah lectures
>   in accordance with the opinion of Maran Ha’Shulchan Aruch that
>   glassware does not require Hag’ala and it may be used for both meat
>   and dairy. [...] According to the Sephardic custom, however, a thorough washing is sufficient, as we have explained.

However Ashkenazim consider that glass absorbs and has a status of Kli Cheres, which is to say that glass dishes are equal to that of pottery (which can become non-kosher, see e.g., [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=4/20/2005)).

Your question mentions wood, but wood absorbs and is kashered through *hagala* ([SA OC 451:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.451.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: Are you suggesting that glass is a Machlokes in Metziut?